# How to group data keeping identity column unchanging

Tags: r, grouping

I have a dataset as below in R.

```
date          jobcategory
2016-01-01     SP    
2016-01-01     DP   
2016-01-01     SP   
2016-01-01     CP   
2016-01-01     DP   
2016-01-01     DP   
2016-01-01     DP   
2016-01-02     SP   
2016-01-02     CP   
2016-01-02     SP   
2016-01-02     CP   
2016-01-02     DP   
2016-01-02     TP   
2016-01-02     DP   
2016-01-02     DP   
2016-01-02     DP   
2016-01-03     SP   
2016-01-03     SP   
2016-01-03     DP   
2016-01-03     DP   
2016-01-03     SP   
2016-01-03     DP   
2016-01-04     CP   
2016-01-04     MP
```

I am trying to group this data in a way to maintain the date field unique,  while getting a count of one of the job categories in the second column as below:

```
date      jobcategory   Count
2016-01-01     SP       2
2016-01-02     SP       2
2016-01-03     SP       3
2016-01-04     SP       0
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution with `table`.

```
> dat <- as.data.frame(table(dat))
> dat <- dat[dat$jobcategory=='SP', ]
> dat


         date jobcategory Freq
13 2016-01-01          SP    2
14 2016-01-02          SP    2
15 2016-01-03          SP    3
16 2016-01-04          SP    0
```

**data**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04"
), class = "factor"), jobcategory = structure(c(4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("CP", "DP", "MP", "SP", "TP"), class = "factor")),
.Names = c("date", "jobcategory"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to `complete` with missing combinations and then get the 'Count'

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- df %>%
        mutate(ind = 1) %>%
        complete(., date, jobcategory, fill = list(ind = 0)) %>% 
        group_by(date, jobcategory) %>% 
        summarise(Count= sum(ind)) %>%
        arrange(jobcategory, date)
res %>%
    filter(jobcategory == "SP")
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   date [4]
#        date jobcategory Count
#       <date>       <chr> <dbl>
#1 2016-01-01          SP     2
#2 2016-01-02          SP     2
#3 2016-01-03          SP     3
#4 2016-01-04          SP     0
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner from base R would be,

```
sapply(unique(df$date), function(i) 
                        length(df$jobcategory[df$jobcategory == 'SP' & i == df$date]))

#[1] 2 2 3 0
```